# YII2. Subselect in join. '=' instead 'in'

Tags: yii2

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks` as t
LEFT JOIN `task2status` as t2s ON t2s.id = (SELECT t2s1.id FROM task2status as t2s1 WHERE t2s1.task_id = t.id ORDER BY t2s1.id  DESC LIMIT 1)
```

In search model:

```
$query = Tasks::find()->alias('t');
$subQuery = Task2status::find()->alias('t2s')->select('t2s.id')->where(['t2s.task_id' => 'tasks.id'])->orderBy('t2s.id desc')->limit(1)->offset(0);
$query->InnerJoin('task2status ts', ['ts.id' => $subQuery]);
```

As a result, I get the following

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tasks` `t` INNER JOIN `task2status` `ts` ON `ts`.`id` IN (SELECT `t2s`.`id` FROM `task2status` `t2s` WHERE `t2s`.`task_id`='tasks.id' ORDER BY `t2s`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1)
```

The 'limit' can not be used in 'in'. Accordingly, an error occurs
And I need to get '=' instead of 'in'. How to get this? what am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance, and sorry for the bad English

Comment: looking to your code  .... why you are using the subquery  .. ??'

Answer (score 0):

If the limit is 1 there is no need for 'in'. Please change limit to 2 and check